# Weight space of a representation of ${\frak sl}(2,\mathbb C)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Suppose $(\pi,V)$ is a finite representation of $SU(2)$. Then there's
>   an induced representation $(\pi_*,V)$ of the complexified ${\frak su}^\mathbb C(2) = {\frak sl}(2,\mathbb C)$. Show that the weight
>   space $\Lambda (\pi_*)$ satisfies
>
> $$ \Lambda (\pi_*) \subset \frac{1}{2}\mathbb Z \alpha $$
>
> where $\alpha$ is one of the roots of  ${\frak sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ .

I know that if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \Lambda (\pi_*)$ are two weights, then they must differ by an integer of the root:

$$ \lambda_1 - \lambda_2 \in \mathbb Z \alpha $$

This form is very suggestive, but I'm having some trouble applying it without knowing anything about the representation.

Since $\alpha (H) = 2$ for $ H = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & -1 \end{array} \right) $, I have:

$$ \lambda_1 (H) - \lambda_2 (H) \in \mathbb Z \alpha(H) = 2\mathbb Z $$

So if I knew that there's at least one weight $\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_2(H)$ is even, then I would deduce that $\lambda_1(H)$ must be even as well (similar if $\lambda_2(H)$ is odd). But I don't know that!

Comment: There is a classification of all irreducible finite dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{sl_{2}}(\mathbb{C}).$ For these representations, the highest weights are in $\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}\alpha.$ Thus, the same holds for all of the weights of irreducible representations (by what you noted about the difference between weights) and by complete reducibility, all weights of any finite dimensional representation.

Comment: Why must two weights differ by an integer of the root?

Answer (score 3):

I'll expand my comment into an answer.

Note that it suffices by complete reducibility to show that for each irreducible finite dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, the weights are in $\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z} \alpha$. Again, by what you mentioned in your question, it suffices to do so for one weight so lets focus on the highest weight of $V$, where we let $\alpha$ be the positive root and $-\alpha$ the negative root.

From here on let, $\mathfrak{g}$ denote $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}.$ Let $E$ be a nonzero element in the root space $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}$ and $F$ be a nonzero element in the root space $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$ such that $[E, F] = H$, where my $H$ is your $H$.

Basically, 
$$E = \left(\begin{array} {rr}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$
and $F$ is its transpose.

Now, let $v$ be a highest weight vector of $V$ (with weight $\omega$.) By definition, a highest weight vector is one that is killed by $E$. Then, for any $n$,

$$F^{n}(v) \in V_{\omega - n\alpha}.$$

By finite-dimensionality, this must stop somewhere i.e. there must be some smallest $n$ such that $V_{\omega - n\alpha} = 0.$

So, we see that $F^{n}v = 0$. Hence, $EF^{n}(v) = 0.$ Now, we use the commutation relations to move everything upwards.

$\begin{align*}
EF^{n}(v) &= [E, F] F^{n-1}(v) + F(EF^{n-1})(v) \\
&= [E, F] F^{n-1}(v) + F [E, F] F^{n-2}(v) + F^{2}EF^{n-2}(v)\\
&= \cdots \\
&= [E, F] F^{n-1}(v) + \cdots F^{n-1}[E, F](v) + F^{n}E(v).
\end{align*}$

Now, we have $E(v) = 0$ because $v$ is a highest weight vector. Additionally, we have $[E, F] = H.$ Finally, we note that $F^{i}(v) \in V_{\omega - i\alpha}$ and hence $H(F^{i}(v)) = (\omega - i \alpha) F^{i}(v).$ Thus, the above equation simplifies to

$$0 = EF^{n}(v) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\omega - i\alpha)\right) F^{n-1}(v).$$

By assumption on $n$, $F^{n-1}(v) \not = 0$ and hence we have

$$0 = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\omega - i \alpha) = n\omega - \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \alpha.$$

Thus, since $v$ is nonzero and hence $n > 0$, we have $\omega = \frac{n-1}{2} \alpha$, as desired.

Comment: Why does it suffice to show this for an irreducible representation.

Comment: @Emily Because they form a basis for all representations. If $\pi_V$ is any complex representation, it will decompose as $\pi_V\cong\displaystyle\bigoplus_{U\in\operatorname{Irr}(G)} k_i \pi_U$ 
 by Maschke’s theorem. In general, these multiplicities $k_i=\langle \chi_V, \chi_{V_i} \rangle_{L^2(G)}$ is calculated as an inner product in the group algebra $\mathbb C[G]$ as $\langle \chi_V, \chi_U \rangle_{L^2(G)}:=\frac{1}G \displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} \chi_U(g) \overline{\chi(g)}$ where $L^2(G) \cong \mathbb C[G]$ viewed as vector spaces.