# Weights of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Let $H,X,Y$ be the standard triple for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, let $\alpha$ be the root of $\mathfrak{t}=i\mathbb{R}H$ in $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}$. Denote the colection of weights of $\pi_*|t$ by $\Lambda(\pi_*)$.
>
> Show that $\Lambda(\pi_*)\subset \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}\alpha$

I'm new to roots and weights so I a little unsure about this. I know that weights are given by $\lambda$ where $V_\lambda=\{v\in V | Hv=\lambda v\}$ and the collection of weights is  $\Lambda(\pi)=\{\lambda| V_\lambda\neq0\}$.
Roots are the weights for the the adjoint representation which are different from zero.

We must show that $V_{\lambda}$ is only non empty when $\lambda=n\alpha/2$. I must be overlooking something as it seems it is never the case that $Hv= \lambda v$?

Comment: There is a very similar question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790804/), but I do not think this is a duplicate. My confusion is much more basic and about begining to work with roots and weights rather than the subtle details of this particular exercise. I must have missed something obvious or perhaps have my definitions wrong.

Comment: It would help you and others to write down what $\pi_\ast$ and $\Lambda(\pi_\ast)$ are, and then look at examples.

Comment: Here $\pi$ is any finite dimensional continuous representation. Not necessarily irreducible.

Comment: Representation of what? And what is $\pi_\ast$? And what examples have you looked at?

Comment: Sorry I should add more information into the this and phrase my confusions better.